# How can I set a primary color in Chakra UI theme?

Tags: reactjs, themes, chakra-ui

I want to set the primary and secondary color in my theme.js/theme.ts. Is there any way to do that?

I am used to work with Material UI components in my React projects.
It is possible to set a palette with 'primary' and 'secondary' there.

I mean something like this:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7bb9e8"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#eb7f7f"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you have defined all color's shades, you can use your custom color as a component's colorSheme:

```
const theme = extendTheme({
   colors: {
     primary: {
      main: "#7bb9e8",
      50: "#e3f2fd",
      100: "#bbdefb",
      200: "#90caf9",
      300: "#64b5f6",
      400: "#42a5f5",
      500: "#2196f3",
      600: "#1e88e5",
      700: "#1976d2",
      800: "#1565c0",
      900: "#0d47a1"
    }
  }
});
```

And your component :

```
<Button colorScheme="primary">Button</Button>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/colors-forked-k9u13?file=/src/App.js:141-187)

Comment: Thats cool. Thank you. Do you know a tool or a website to generate these shades?

Comment: Those tools come from Material, but you can use it with Chakra as well : 
https://material.io/inline-tools/color/,   http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%23b4b65b

Answer (score 3):

According to this section: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theming/customize-theme#using-theme-extensions

You don't have to pass `color='primary'` everywhere.

Just create custom theme and then set primary as default color.

This example shows how to set Cyan as default color for every component.

```
const theme = extendTheme(
  {
    colors: {
      primary: baseTheme.colors.cyan
    },
    breakpoints,
  },
  withDefaultColorScheme({
    colorScheme: 'primary'
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  [customize the theme](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme) in any possible way :

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7bb9e8"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#eb7f7f"
    }
  }
});
```

Then pass this theme to `ChakraProvider`

```
//index.js

    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ChakraProvider>
```

And you will be able to use your own colors accessing the theme via useTheme hook:

```
import { useTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
...
  const theme = useTheme();
...
<Button bg={theme.colors.primary.main}>Button</Button>
```

or override a component styles globally [inside the `component` object](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme#customizing-single-components)

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/colors-mov1q?file=/src/App.js:144-171)

Comment: This is not actually the answer I was looking for because I have to pass the style to every button in my app. The problem is when I want to change the color of all buttons I will have to change the background of every single button. 
In Material UI you can set the primary color and every Button, TextField, ... will be affected by the change in the theme. 
Is there a way to set the color (and later other properties) of all components at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can set two variants of primary colors with `default` and `_dark` property. It will be used depending on actual color mode (light/dark theme).

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'

const theme = extendTheme({
  initialColorMode: 'light',
  semanticTokens: {
    colors: {
      text: {
        default: '#16161D',
        _dark: '#ade3b8',
      },
      primary: {
        default: '#FF0080',
        _dark: '#fbec8f',
      },
})

export default theme
```